# Loop Break When

Tags: repeat

I am using code published by Kim Tsao ( http://www.kimtsao.com/Kim_Tsao/Code/Entries/2011/9/30_Reflections_on_the_lake_files/tRFLP_id.r ) for fragment analysis. I am trying to write the final chunk of code into a loop as opposed to manually running the code for each sample. However I can't get the loop to break correctly after it prints "End of sample list"

```
x <- 0 
repeat {
     x <- x+1 
     if (x<= length(samplelist)){
         samplelist[x]
         output = matchSample(x, weightby=c("Height","AreaInPoint"),threshold=4) 

         if (nrow(output)>1){graphOutput(output)} else {print(samplelist[x]);print(output)}
     } else { print("End of sample list.")}
     if (print("End of sample list.")){
         break
     }
```

Comment: Why is your print statement in an if-statement?

Comment: I was able to get the loop working for my data set with the following code: